# Как сделать плавное отображение объекта при Drag and Drop?

Tags: java, android, drag-n-drop

Есть 2 ImageView.
1я - подложка, 2я - объект, который нужно перемещать по 1-й ImageView с помощью Drag and Drop.
В моей реализации 2я ImageView перемещается "скачками" или ступеньками, см.видео. Как мне добиться плавного отображения перемещения. Также в текущей реализации нет возможности точного позиционирования таскаемого объекта.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/15kphsztagwfx6a/device-2016-08-01-165716.mp4?dl=0

**Layout с изображениями**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_back_image_frag2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_watermark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

**Исходный код фрагмента**

```
public class AddWatermarkFragment extends Fragment {

ImageView backImageView, watermarkImageView;
private static final int CHOOSE_BASE_PHOTO = 1001;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_watermark, null);

    backImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_back_image_frag2);
    watermarkImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_watermark);
    if(WatermarkSettings.getInstance().getSelectedImageUri() != null) {
        Bitmap galleryBitmap = null;
        try {
            galleryBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    WatermarkSettings.getInstance().getSelectedImageUri());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        backImageView.setImageBitmap(galleryBitmap);
        pickImageFromGallery();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Выберите фоновое изображение!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    watermarkImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    //view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ACTION_MOVE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    watermarkImageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
            switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int width = size.x;
                    int height = size.y;
                    int x = (int)dragEvent.getX();
                    int y = (int)dragEvent.getY();
                    Log.d("Drad Log: ","Старт. Касание x: " + x + " y: " + y);
                    Log.d("Drad Log: ","Размер экрана. ширина: " + width + " высота: " + height);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    float X1 = dragEvent.getX();
                    float Y1 = dragEvent.getY();
                    view = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
                    view.setX(X1 - (view.getWidth() / 2));
                    view.setY(Y1 - (view.getHeight() / 2));
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй этот код для перемещения:

```
ImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                view.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();                     
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

У меня перемещается достаточно плавно таким способом.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. То что нужно.